# SuperTest can be used for Spring based REST API

Tags: rest, supertest

SuperTest npm is used to test node.js based REST API's. I want to know whether SuperTest can be used for testing JAVA Spring based REST API's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can use it to test any REST API irrespective of the technology which was used for implementing that API. The fact that a majority prefers to test with SuperTest node.js REST API's is because it is probably much more convenient(using the same technology, in this case JS, for developing the API and for testing it as well). The same is with the Spring Java REST API's which I prefer to test with the Spring MVC Test framework because it's more convenient for me to use Java also for developing my tests.

Comment: Thanks, Mr.Loan. That helps